# Python factor level combinations

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to create a python version of the attentional network task. See this as a reference (page 3): http://www.researchgate.net/publication/7834908_The_Activation_of_Attentional_Networks

I have a total of 216 trials. Half of which will be "congruent", half are "incongruent". Furthermore, a third of the 216 will be "nocue", another third will be "center", and the final third will be "spatial"

Each of the 216 trials will be some combination of the above (e.g. congruent-spatial, incongruent-none)

This is how I'm creating those trials right now:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

#set number of trials
numTrials = 216
numCongruent = numTrials / 2
numCue = numTrials / 3

#create shuffled congruency conditions
congruent = ["congruent"] * numCongruent
incongruent = ["incongruent"] * numCongruent
congruentConditions = congruent + incongruent
random.shuffle(congruentConditions)

#create shuffled cue conditions
noCue = ["none"] * numCue
centerCue = ["center"] * numCue
spatialCue = ["spatial"] * numCue
cueConditions = noCue + centerCue + spatialCue
random.shuffle(cueConditions)

#put everything into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

congruentArray = np.asarray(congruentConditions)
cueArray = np.asarray(cueConditions)
df["congruent"] = congruentArray
df["cue"] = cueArray
print df
```

2 questions...

1. Now, this works, but one important point is ensuring even distribution of the levels.

For example, I need to ensure that all of the "congruent" trials have an equal number of "nocue", "center", and "spatial" trials. And conversely, all of the "nocue" trials, for example, need to half an equal number of "congruent" and "incongruent" trials.

This is currently not ensured given the way I'm randomly shuffling the conditions. This would even out over an infinite sample size, but that is not the case here.

How would I ensure an equal distribution?

I've taken a look at the cartesian product (https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), but I'm not entirely that will help me achieve the equality problem

2. Once the above has been solved, I then need to ensure that in the final shuffled list, each trial type (e.g. congruent-spatial) follows each other trial type an equal number of times in the list order

Comment: I've been puzzling over the second part of your question, which is a much deeper (and more interesting!) problem. It's up to you, but I think you'd have a better chance of getting a good answer if you posted it as a separate question. Ideally you could pose it in a more general way (e.g. *"How can I generate random sequences where each unique item follows each other unique item an equal number of times?"*).

Comment: good point. I'll break this up into a separate question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy option is to generate a list of the 216 trials and shuffle it:

```
In [16]: opt1 = ["congruent", "incongruent"]

In [17]: opt2 = ["nocue", "center", "spatial"]

In [18]: from itertools import product

In [19]: trials = list(product(opt1, opt2))*36

In [20]: np.random.shuffle(trials)
```

trials will then be a randomly ordered list with 36 of each of the pairs.

EDIT: Your edit is a harder problem, and honestly, I'd need to think more about it to figure out if there is a solution or to prove that you can't have that desired property.

If "close enough" to even works, the best I could come up with is a bogosort approach: shuffle the list, check whether all of the a->b counts are between 4-8, and start over if they're not. Generally runs in 1-5 seconds on my machine:

```
def checkvals(v):
    return all(x in (4,5,6,7,8) for x in v[1].value_counts().values)

def checkall(trials):
    return all(checkvals(v) for k, v in pd.DataFrame(zip(trials, trials[1:])).groupby(0))

while not checkall(trials):
    np.random.shuffle(trials)
```

Comment: thanks, this is much more elegant and works as intended. However, I forgot to include the second part to my question which pertains to the ordering of the final shuffled list. I have edited the question to reflect this.